# Quartz Schduler Trigger level concurrency

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have used quartz jdbcdatastore for scheduling jobs with spring. In it , with the help of 
@DisallowConcurrentExecution we can achieve some type of concurrency but i want to achieve concurrency between 2 triggers scheduling the same job.

Basically, when one trigger is fired and running the job another trigger should not be able to run the same job.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code,

```
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

            JobKey jobKey1 = new JobKey("job1","group1");
            JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(MyJob.class).withIdentity(jobKey1).build();


            CronTrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger1", "triggergroup1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/1 * * * * ?")).build();

            if(scheduler.checkExists(trigger.getKey())) {
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger.getKey(), trigger);
            }else {
                scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
            }


            CronTrigger trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("trigger2", "triggergroup2")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/1 * * * * ?")).build();


            if(scheduler.checkExists(trigger1.getKey())) {
                scheduler.rescheduleJob(trigger1.getKey(), trigger1);
            }else {
                scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger1);
            }

            scheduler.start();
```

and the code in job class is,

```
         System.out.println("Thread Id "+Thread.currentThread().getId() +" "+context.getJobDetail().getKey());

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        System.out.println("Stop Thread Id "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
```

Output is :

```
Thread Id 20 group1.job1
Thread Id 21 group2.job2
Stop Thread Id 20
Stop Thread Id 21
```

Comment: are the 2 triggers pointing to the same job key? If they are then you should still be able to achieve the same concurrency (i havent tested it though). Did you try running your set up? Did you see concurrent run?

Comment: @Srinivas I have used same jobkeys but still it is not working..I have added my code snippet can you please review it if something is wrong or missing in it.

Comment: where is group2.job2 defined. i dont see it in your snippet. From the output it looks like group1.job1 is not run concurrently.